# keycloak - trusted hosts in client registration policies using kcadm

Tags: keycloak

i'm having trouble finding how I can add a trusted host using kcadm cli tool.  This is in realm->realm settings->client registration->client registration policies->trusted hosts

Answer (score 0):

it's part of components.

kcadm get components -r demorealm -F "name,id,config(*)" -q name="Trusted Hosts"

I found that if you export the database, it will produce a json file and you will find all the information that you need there.